# How should I use TLS on Akka 2.6.3 Scala?

Tags: scala, akka

I was using following TLS class for Akka 2.5.0, but the `AkkaSSLConfig` is deprecated on Akk 2.6.0 and above.

```
case class TlsContext(
                       sslContext: SSLContext,
                       sslConfig: Option[AkkaSSLConfig] = None,
                       enabledCipherSuites: Option[immutable.Seq[String]] = None,
                       enabledProtocols: Option[immutable.Seq[String]] = None,
                       clientAuth: Option[TLSClientAuth] = None,
                       sslParameters: Option[SSLParameters] = None) {

  def firstSession =
    NegotiateNewSession(
      enabledCipherSuites, enabledProtocols, clientAuth, sslParameters)
}
```

How should I change above code to use for upgraded Akka version

Answer (score 0):

The deprecated `AkkaSSLConfig` should be replaced by constructing a `javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine` in you own code.

The specific parameters from `NegotiateNewSession` are applied using the following methods on `SSLEngine`

```
SSLEngine#setEnabledCipherSuites
SSLEngine#setEnabledProtocols
SSLEngine#setNeedClientAuth
SSLEngine#setSSLParameters
```

There is a sample for TLS streams in the Akka docs showing how to first construct an `SSLContext` and then a `SSLEngine` from that here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-io.html#tls